# Calculate and decide the type of the singularities of the function $\frac{z^2}{1-e^{z^3}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

The task is to find the singularities of the function $$f(z) = \frac{z^2}{1-e^{z^3}}$$ and decide their type.

So I started by finding the singularities. I got to $z^3  = 2\pi ki$ for every $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

So:

$$z_0 = \sqrt[3]{2\pi k} e^{\frac{\pi}{6}i},  z_1 = \sqrt[3]{2\pi k} e^{\frac{5\pi}{6}i}, z_2 = \sqrt[3]{2\pi k} e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}i}, z_3 = \sqrt[3]{2\pi k} e^{-\frac{\pi}{6}i}, z_4 = \sqrt[3]{2\pi k} e^{-\frac{5\pi}{6}i}, z_5 = \sqrt[3]{2\pi k} e^{\frac{\pi}{2}i}$$

for every $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and also the point $z=0$.

My problem is to determine their type. I though that $z=0$ is a removable singularity, but calculating the limit at $0$ of the functions using l'hopital's rule gave out the the limit is not finite.

About the other singularities I think that they are poles, since the limit at them is equal to $\infty$. But does it really enough to prove it?

I was not asked to find the order of the poles, but it would be nice if someone can show me how to do it here.

Hep would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $z \to 0$, $e^{z^3} = 1 + z^3 + O(z^6)$ so $f(z) = z^2/(-z^3 + O(z^6)) = -z^{-1} + O(z^2)$, thus $0$ is a pole of order $1$.

The other singularities are also poles of order $1$, because they are simple zeros of the denominator:

$$ \dfrac{d}{dz}(1 - e^{z^3}) = - 3 z^2 e^{z^3} \ne 0 \ \text{when}\ z \ne 0$$

Comment: Thanks!. Is it a known claim that if $z_0$ is a simple zero of the denominator then it is a simple pole?

Comment: Yes: if $z_0$ is a simple zero of $g(z)$ and $f(z_0) \ne 0$, then $z_0$ is a simple pole of $f(z)/g(z)$.